# If I were to clone myself, am I halachically the parent of my clone?

Tags: halacha, children-parenting, biology

This is because my DNA is replicated to clone myself. Hence, it comes from me, and I am its material originator just like a parent is the originator of the child (materially speaking). So would the parent-child relevant halacha apply in this situation?

EDIT: The question assumes some form of futuristic technology where people can be cloned in a lab through someone's DNA.

Comment: Try https://www.koltorah.org/halachah/torah-perspectives-on-cloning-by-rabbi-chaim-jachter

Comment: Is there a reason to assume that DNA is relevant halachically?

Comment: A child is the product of one partners genetic material combining with anothers to create new genetic material. Cloning the same material may just be giving the original's parents another identical child.

Comment: It may halachically be defined as parentless

Comment: Which type of cloning are you talking about ? Ivf ? Or some futuristic technology where this person is created in a lab? If this person is created in a lab then it's not halachicaly human because it's origin was not human.

Comment: @MosesSupposes Because its origin would be me, a material human being, its not entirely built from scratch

Comment: @Shababnik I edited it in the question. Also why? Like, regular human parenting/birth is just creating a human via a woman's womb through giving one's DNA right? Replace the womb with a cloning machine, but the process is the same, it still has a partial origin of a human? Sure, only 50% but still, it would need to be taken into account, no?

Comment: To clarify my comment,  what I meant by IVF is embryo splitting; which begins with ivf. Another option is SCNT.  Both use a uterus. Halacha uses origin as a factor. If a woman were to give birth to a cow then the cow would be human

Comment: @Shababnik I'm not very familiar with those terms, but I'm just thinking more of a hypothetical scenario where someone can provide their DNA and end up cloning themselves through a machine. I don't know if a uterus would change anything halachically?

Comment: @setszu in a case where the person is created in a lab,  a better question would be if that "person" would be considered a human being at all.

Comment: @Shababnik I recall reading somewhere that they would both be considered a person AND have a soul. I might be wrong, but I just assumed that for the question. But perhaps you can also be a parent to a non-human thing? Idk, this is more nuanced than I initially thought lol

Comment: @setszu you probably wouldn't be halachically considered a parent of a non-human thing made by cloning DNA in a machine.